# Rasperry Pi Access point: Assign a fixed IP to a client

Tags: raspberry-pi3, dhcp, access-point

I configured an access point with custom DNS on my raspberry pi according to the official documentation: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md

Now I want to assign a **fixed IP address** to one of my clients via the installed dhcp/dnsmasq service (on my access point). What **content** do I have to add to **which file**?

Comment: Note: I removed all my configuration files / content as this could be interpreted very misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` is for setting dhcp roules for raspberry network interfaces as client not as AP.
See [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os) for further details.

Try to add this line to `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` please:

```
dhcp-host=[MAC ADDRESS],[NAME],[STATIC IP ADDRESS]
```

**EDIT1**: tested on  my RPi3B+ and it's working fine.